# PHP - Date Format to include a string

Tags: php, datetime, formatting

I am trying to format a PHP date to be of the following format:

***Wednesday 3rd November 2021 at 11:01am***

My code is below: 
*$date = new DateTime($dateOfChange); 

$date = $date->format('l jS F Y "at" g:ia');*

I have tried: 
*$date = $date->format('l jS F Y "at" g:ia');* // displays: "am01" 
*$date = $date->format('l jS F Y at g:ia');* // displays: am01

I can't see a relevant section in the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Escaping of literal characters can be done by prefixing them with a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```php
$date->format('l jS F Y \a\t g:ia');
```

You need to escape characters that are not intended to be used for date values.

Note that if you're using `"` instead of `'` for your format string you'll need to double escape `n`, `t` and `r` characters as PHP will interpret them as newlines, tabs etc...

For example:

```php
$date->format("l jS F Y \a\\t g:ia");
```

Comment: Should not need a _double_ backslash before the `t`, in a text literal delimited with single quotes.

Comment: @CBroe I've updated my answer. Hopefully more informative!

Comment: @LeviCole Great stuff - thank you!